# Adding an "end of file" for a JSON?

Tags: json, exchange-server

I'm building an app using Knockout. The end result is a JSON that I want to fire back over to the server. But, the data is very complex, and as a result, can grow in size to be a few mb's.

I'm thinking it might be smart to introduce an "end of file" marker so that if someone closes a browser window or if the upload gets interrupted, I can handle that situation accordingly.

This might seem too general for SO, but what would be the right approach? Just appending a string to the end of the JSON that I look for, server-side?

Comment: How about `\r\n`? That's what Twitter is doing: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/processing

Comment: That's a good idea if I decide to actually add an EoF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is either parseable, or it isn't. If the upload was truncated/cut off, you'd end up with an invalid data structure anyways, so there's no point in an EOF marker.

e.g.

```
{'this':{'is':{'a':{'complex':'structure'}
                                          ^---upload terminates here.
```

That's missing `}}}` at the end, so it's invalid json, and the parser will barf on it. If the parser barfs, you know something didn't work out.

Comment: Except I'm taking the JSON, and storing it in a MYSQL database, so the server really doesn't know anything about JSON.

Comment: You can run it through a json decoder before doing the insertion. If the decode fails, then don't insert it.